# install R package from 32bit to 64bit

Tags: r, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit

I have [this R package](http://perswww.kuleuven.be/~u0043181/software/) (MRwarping_1.0.zip). It installs on the 32bit 
windows PC of a colleague but fails to install on my 64bit ubuntu (and 
gives a very strange error message). I was wondering whether

- I can install it (on my 64 bit ubuntu).
- if yes, what are the requiered steps to do that

Comment: R CMD INSTALL MRwarping_1.0.zip
Error in rawToChar(block[seq_len(ns)]) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\n\0\0\0\0\0\xbaR\035?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\n\0\0\0MRwarping/PK\003\004\n\0\0\0\0\0\xbaR\035?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\017\0\0\0MRwarping/data/PK\003\004\024\0\002\0\b\0\xbaR\035?3'

Comment: That is very strange, indeed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MRwarping_1.0.zip is a Windows binary build of the package.  You need the package source to be able to install it on anything other than Windows.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I should be able to get that. Would you know of a link where it is explained how to build a package source under linux?

Comment: @user189035: it's in the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) manual: [Section 1.3 Checking and building packages](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Checking-and-building-packages).  Also see [Appendix A of R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Essential-and-useful-other-programs-under-a-Unix_002dalike) to ensure you have all the necessary tools installed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Joshua's answer, this error happened to me also when I tried to install a package that was a binary build for Linux, but compressed in `.zip` format instead of `.tar.gz` format.

So, when you install a binary package for Linux, it must be a `.tar.gz` file. You can use tools like 7-zip to uncompress the `.zip` file and recompress it as `.tar.gz`. Alternatively, use `unzip ZIPFILE` to extract the zip into a folder and `tar -czf package.tar.gz FOLDER` to recompress the folder to a `.tar.gz`-file.